# Filtering by a selection of different keys in Overpass?

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I want to search for multiple key types in Overpass Turbo such as "natural," "waterway," "landuse," etc, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried it like this, but doing so gives me just one of these tags instead of all 3.

```
 way
  ["landuse"]
  ["waterway"]
  ["natural"]
  (around: 100, 41.410239, -84.017210);
out;
```

Comment: Have you tried using the wizard overpass provides?

Answer (score 0):

A union operation is needed for this kind of "or" operation (that's the round brackets in line 1 and 5):

```
(
 way["landuse"](around: 100, 41.410239, -84.017210);
 way["waterway"](around: 100, 41.410239, -84.017210);
 way["natural"](around: 100, 41.410239, -84.017210);
);  
out geom;
```

As an alternative, you can also use regular expressions for keys:

```
way[~"^(landuse|waterway|natural)$"~"."](around: 100, 41.410239, -84.017210);
out geom;
```